# Rails - Rendering a view with a different action?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

From what I understand, you can use render to have a view within a view. What I have been trying to use it for is to have a display page and in this page, there are some buttons. One button would show/hide the form for creating an activity. Essentially, the page would display the activities and allow the user to create more by clicking on the corresponding button and filling out the form.

I have attempted to render the "new" page that corresponds to the "new" action but I have run into the following issue

> NoMethodError in Activities#display
>
> undefined method `to_key' for
>   Activity::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x694e270

Searching up on this error, I think it involves the "display" action within my activities controller and how it does not expect a "form_for". I do not know how to fix this issue or if I am using render correctly.

What I am wondering is if this is possible or recommended as the examples I have seen seem to utilize render when there are shared elements among the html so using render would cut down the code. The display page would be the only page that has form for creating activities so I could simply just add the html code instead.

Any advice or help would be appreciated, thanks!

Activities Display HTML:

```
<nav aria-label="...">

  <% @activity.each do |activity| %>

      <div class = "row text-center">
        <div class = 'col-md-4'>
          <h3>
            <%= activity.a_name %>
          </h3>
        </div>
      </div>

  <% end %>

  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <h2 align = "center">Activities</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-group">
      <div class="panel text-center">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Collapsible list group</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <h1>ONE</h1>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Three</li>
          </ul>
          <div class="panel-footer">Footer</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <ul class="pager">

    <li class="previous"><a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span>Previous </a></li>
    <li class="next"><a href="#"> Next<span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span></a></li>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <a href="new" class="btn_act">Add Activity</a>
    </div>

    <% render 'activities/new'%>

  </ul>


</nav>
```

Activities _new HTML:

```
<body>
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>

<%= form_for @activity do |a| %>
    <div class = "form-group">
      <div class = "row top-buffer text-center">
        <div class='col-md-3'>
          <%= a.label :a_name, 'Activity Name' %>:
          <%= a.text_field :a_name %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class ="row top-buffer text-center">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <%= a.submit 'Create', class: 'btn btn-primary'%>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>

</body>
```

Activities Controller:

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  def display
    @activity = Activity.all

  end

  def index
    @activity = Activity.all
  end

  def show
    @activity = Activity.all
  end

  def new
    @activity = Activity.new
  end

  def create
    @activity = Activity.create(activity_params)
    if @activity.save!
      flash[:success] = 'Activity created successfully!'
      redirect_to activities_display_path
    else
      flash[:error] = 'ERROR: Activity was not saved!'
      #render_to_string #normally would have it render to the name of view ex: :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @activity = Activity.update(activity_params)
    if @activity.save
      flash[:success] = 'Activity successfully updated!'
      redirect_to root
    else
      flash[:error] = 'ERROR: Activity failed to update'
      render_to_string
    end
  end

  private
    def activity_params
      params.require(:activity).permit(:a_name)
    end

end
```

**EDIT - 03/10/17**
Managed to fix the error above. Turns out I needed to add 
"@activity = Activity.new" into the "display" action in the controller. After that, I changed the "@activity = Activity.all" to "@activities = Activity.all".
Then in the display view, I changed

```
  <% @activity.each do |activity| %>
```

to

```
  <% @activities.each do |activity| %>
```

and the render was successful. Thanks for all the advice and help!

Answer (score 0):

As a naming convention I would rename `@activities` to `@activity` in your new, create, edit and update actions and their associated views. As for the error, `form_for` should be used for a single object, not a collection. It should probably be this:

```
  <% @activities.each do |activity| %>
      <div class = "row text-center">
        <div class = 'col-md-4'>
          <h3>
            <%= activity.a_name %>
          </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Alright, thanks for the advice! I updated the controller and the views accordingly. However I still have the same error (NoMethodError) which is due to the form_for within the "_new" view which uses form_for.  I do not know how to fix this issue as I believe I require form_for in order to create instances of a model using the user input.

Comment: Managed to fix the issue. Thank you for the advice